# HTML 5 canvas attribute click

Tags: html, html5-canvas

so this question is on html5 canvas the pic has the question we did in school but still do not know the answer to

[image: so this question is on html5 canvas the pic has the question we did in school but still do not know the answer to]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to accomplish this problem

Number 1 by using an `EventListener` in JavaScript:

```js
var canvas, context;

function drawBox() {
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.strokeRect(20, 20, canvas.width - 20, canvas.height - 20);
}

function clickReporter(e) {
  console.log("clicked");
}

canvas = document.getElementById("clickCanvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
drawBox();

// Add the eventlistener
canvas.addEventListener("click", clickReporter);
```

```html
<canvas id="clickCanvas" width="300" height="300">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas</canvas>
```

Numer 2 by adding the `EventListener` in the HTML tag:

```js
var canvas, context;

function drawBox() {
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.strokeRect(20, 20, canvas.width - 20, canvas.height - 20);
}

function clickReporter(e) {
  console.log("clicked");
}

canvas = document.getElementById("clickCanvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
drawBox();
```

```html
<!--- Add the eventlistener --->
<canvas id="clickCanvas" width="300" height="300" onclick="clickReporter()">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas</canvas>
```

Comment: thanks man the first one clearly ,but in the second one the "onclick" is an attribute right ? , it fires a function, so are you saying that the attribute behaves as a listener ?.

Comment: `onclick` is indeed an `Attribute`. That attribute is an `Event Attribute`. With the `addEventListener()` you add an `Event`. So simply seated is behaves like a listener.